# define attribute in arff file using java

Tags: java, csv, weka

I'm using j48 method in weka. My sample training data .arff file is follows,

```
 @relation l4_tbl_final

    @attribute MouseVariance numeric
    @attribute EyeValue numeric
    @attribute SocialTime numeric
    @attribute KeyWords numeric
    @attribute InvolvedTime numeric
    @attribute grade {B,A,C}

    @data
    2731.35,87,47.55,0,49.7,B
    864.891,55,0,0,94.33,B
    2495.8,1386,0,2,71.75,A
    1104.04,4490,0,0,61.91,B
```

The first 5 values are parameters and based on that Grade 'A','B','C' is given.

Now I need to provide test data set and predict the grade of those data. for that I should provide testdata.arff file as follows (? marks at the grade)

```
@attribute MouseVariance numeric
@attribute EyeValue numeric
@attribute SocialTime numeric
@attribute KeyWords numeric
@attribute InvolvedTime numeric
@attribute grade {B,A,C}

@data
2731.35,87,47.55,0,49.7,?
864.891,55,0,0,94.33,?
2495.8,1386,0,2,71.75,?
1104.04,4490,0,0,61.91,?
```

I used the following java code to convert sql databases to csv and after that csv converted to arff:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("MouseVariance"));
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("EyeValue"));
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("SocialTime"));
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("KeyWords"));
        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("InvolvedTime"));
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("?");

                i++;
    }
```

but when I create the arff file in that way the attribute is shows as

```
@attribute grade {numaric} value.
```

so expected grade is not predicted.
but if it is as follows that would solved the problem.

```
 @attribute grade {B,A,C}
```

How can I solve that??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Attribute does not know the list of available nominal values in the list.

Perhaps the [AddValues](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/AddValues.html) filter may help in adding these items to the list.  You could add the values of A, B and C to the nominal variable, thereby making them consistent with the training data.

If this is not the issue, please provide more of the code and the generated output and I will look a little further.

Hope this Helps!